# Minimise vertex loss converting DCG to DAG

Tags: graphs, dag

I have a DCG that I want to lay out with the parents on the left and children to the right.  I want to maximise the number of all children present to the right of all parents whilst minimising the number of children present to their left of one of their "ancestors".

The specific graph in question is the [Foresight Obesity graph](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/296290/obesity-map-full-hi-res.pdf) that I have copied into a complex systems mapping tool I am building.

I was hoping to find an algorithm to prune a DCG to form a DAG, whilst minimising the number of edges that need to be removed.  I can then feed the DAG into a Tree layout algorithm, potentially adding some additional temporary edges to bias grouping vertexes which have the same label / category.  My searches for "Prune DCG", "Convert DCG to DAG", etc haven't yielded anything yet.  Is there an algorithm for doing this already?  Can another be "repurposed" for this task?

Comment: Have you looked at [feedback arc set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_arc_set)?

Comment: This sounds very promising @JohnL. thank you!